# Kdenlive melt-7 dependency broke package manager

Tags: package-management, kdenlive

Any kind soul able to help out?

I tried to install a package and received an error from the terminal that

```
sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I get the following terminal output:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdenlive:
 kdenlive depends on melt-7; however:
  Package melt-7 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kdenlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.6+22.04.20220217-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kdenlive
```

I've tried removing and purging Kdenlive to no avail - the package manager still seems to be broken.

(ETA: I installed Kdenlive via the PPA)

Trying sudo apt-get install -f yields this output:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 liblept5 libmlt-data libopencv-calib3d4.5d libopencv-contrib4.5d libopencv-dnn4.5d
  libopencv-features2d4.5d libopencv-flann4.5d libopencv-highgui4.5d libopencv-ml4.5d
  libopencv-objdetect4.5d libopencv-video4.5d libtesseract4 melt
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmlt7-data melt-7
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmlt7-data melt-7
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 145 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/121 kB of archives.
After this operation, 773 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 391414 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmlt7-data_7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmlt7-data (7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt7-data_7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mlt-7/avformat/blacklist.txt', which is also in package libmlt-data 7.4.0-1build1
Preparing to unpack .../melt-7_7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking melt-7 (7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/melt-7_7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/melt-7', which is also in package melt 7.4.0-1build1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt7-data_7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/melt-7_7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Ubuntu version:** Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

**PPA installed from:** ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable

Any ideas for how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please add Ubuntu version and ppa-details to your question.

Comment: @mook765 - done, thanks.

Comment: what was the state of your system when the install -f was run - was it after you removed kdenlive? Did you also remove the ppa from sources?

Comment: I wonder where the package `melt-7` comes from, it's not in the Ubuntu repositories and not in the ppa.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this issue, run the following commands.

```
sudo apt remove kdenlive libmlt7-data melt libmlt-data
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

Credit goes to [sniff122 on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/xq9mti/comment/iqjucwa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Answer (score 2):

These three commands helped me:

```
sudo apt remove libmlt7-data melt-7 kdenlive
sudo dkpg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

i needed to explicitly remove `melt-7`